# Timestamp in mock-up mode

Tags: michelson

Is there a way to control what `NOW` returns in the mock-up mode?

If not, this could be done via a special command in the client to increase it. This seems important for testing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mockup mode saves its context in a JSON file, I have not checked but I think that editing the `context/shell_header/timestamp` entry affects the value returned by the `NOW` instruction.

Comment: That's one way to do it, but could you confirm that there isn't indeed a command to do it directly from the tezos-client?

Comment: To the best of my knowledge there is no command. There is an open issue on adding a flag to the `run script` command for that: https://gitlab.com/tezos/tezos/-/issues/718

Answer (score 0):

The initial timestamp used by mockup mode can be modified by passing an appropriately formatted protocol constants configuration file when creating the mockup. See the documentation [here](https://tezos.gitlab.io/user/mockup.html#tune-mockup-parameters). In particular, it is the `initial_timestamp` that should be modified.

`protocol-constants.json`:

```
{
  "preserved_cycles": 2,
<... snip for brevity ...>  
  "chain_id": "NetXynUjJNZm7wi",
  "initial_timestamp": "1988-01-12T00:00:00Z"
}
```

and then,

```
$ tezos-client -mode mockup --base-dir ~/.tezos-mockup create mockup \
              --protocol-constants protocol-constants.json
```

Now,

```
 $ tezos-client -mode mockup --base-dir ~/.tezos-mockup \
              get timestamp
 1988-01-12T00:00:00Z
```